# transform a matrix to another one using loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix (11x42) and I would like to apply a function for each column one by one and put the result back in a new 11x42 matrix with a new name and modified column names.

I am not used to loops so I am a bit struggling. Here is what I have so far, but not working.

```
 for (i in 1:ncol(matrix))
  {
    res[[i]] <-residuals(lm(matrix[,i]~HW))
  }
```

I would like to also use the function `paste0("new_", i)` to change the names of each column.

Here I was trying to create 42 vectors (res1 to res 42) that I would cbind into a new matrix. But it's not working. And I am pretty sure that could be done within the loop as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a matrix you should use `apply` with margin `2`, i.e.

```
new_mat <- apply(your_mat, 2, function(i) residuals(lm(i~HW)))
colnames(new_mat) <- paste0('new_', colnames(your_mat))
```

Comment: Mmmh, I don't get it, sorry. 

"your_mat" is my original matrix and "m1" is my new one? 

Do I have to insert a function somewhere ? 

Why you use "i" instead of my original "matrix[,i]" ? I need to do a lm of each column of my original matrix one by one, that's why I did that.

Comment: I m not looping over the index. I am iterating over each column. So `i` represents a column. `m1` is just a name I gave the new matrix inside the function. You will name the final object by `a_name <- apply(your_mat, 2, ...)`

Comment: Ok, I still don't get it... 

Do I still have to insert that part within a loop starting with  `for (i in 1:ncol(matrix))` ?
So far, I only get that error, but I am pretty sure I am not doing the right thing. 

`Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Called from: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste0("new_", 
    i))
Browse[1]> `

Comment: No you are right. I made an error. You dont need `for()` loop. This is done by `apply`. Let me fix it

Comment: Thanks! It's working. The only thing is that "new_mat" columns names are "new1", "new2",... I would like to keep the original columns names from "your_mat" and just add "new_" in front of each one.